# Exception Handling of multiple user inputs Python

Tags: python, exception, while-loop, user-input

I'm currently practicing on how to raise custom exceptions with multiple user input. How do I get to this desired output?

```
Terminal:
Enter assignment mark (0-20): 25
Assignment mark must be between 0 and 20
Enter assignment mark (0-20): 2
Enter project mark (0-30): 50
Project mark must be between 0 and 30
Enter project mark (0-30):
```

Current output:

```
Enter assignment mark (0-20): 25
Assignment mark must be between 0 and 20
Enter assignment mark (0-20): 2
Enter project mark (0-30): 50
Project mark must be between 0 and 30
Enter assignment mark (0-20):
```

It keeps looping back to the first question.

I appreciate anybody who can help and explain. Thanks!

Code:

```
class rangeError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

while True:
   try:
       assignment_mark = int(input("Enter assignment mark (0-20): "))
       if assignment_mark > 20 or assignment_mark < 0:
           raise rangeError("Assignment mark must be between 0 and 20")


       project_mark = int(input("Enter project mark (0-30): "))
       if project_mark > 30 or project_mark < 0:
           raise rangeError("Project mark must be between 0 and 30")


       final_exam_mark = int(input("Enter final exam mark (0-50): "))
       if final_exam_mark > 50 or final_exam_mark < 0:
           raise rangeError("Exam mark must be between 0 and 50")


       total_mark = assignment_mark + project_mark + final_exam_mark

       print(total_mark)


   except ValueError as e:
      print("Please enter integers")
   except rangeError as e:
      print(e)
   except Exception as e:
      print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an exception occurs you start with the try block again (due to `while True`). You never terminate  or check whether the values have already been defined. When you reach the total_mark output, you also start all over again. I would suggest you retrieve the values separately using a function, to avoid duplication. Note the `return mark`, which exits the function and therefore the `while True` as soon as a proper value has been provided:

```
class rangeError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

        
def get_mark(name, val_range):
    lo, hi = val_range
    
    while True:
       try:
           mark = int(input(f"Enter {name} mark ({lo}-{hi}): "))
           if mark > val_range[1] or mark < val_range[0]:
               raise rangeError(f"{name.capitalize()} mark must be between {lo} and {hi}")

           return mark
                
       except ValueError as e:
          print("Please enter integers")
       except rangeError as e:
          print(e)
       except Exception as e:
          print(e)

assignment_mark = get_mark("assignment", [0, 20])
project_mark = get_mark("project", [0, 30])
final_exam_mark = get_mark("final exam", [0, 50])
         
total_mark = assignment_mark + project_mark + final_exam_mark 
    
print(total_mark)
```

Answer (score 0):

When the error occurs in the `try` block, Python will jump to the exception blocks and find the correct error to raise.  When the error is handled, it loops to the top of the while-block.  That is why your code is starting over.

There are a couple of ways to handle it.  One is to have a while loop for each input. Another way is to set variables in your global scope that hold the values of `assignment_mark`, `project_mark`, and `final_exam_mark`.  You can then check if the value exists and skip to the correct chunk of code.  Since all three of your checks are for a range, you can wrap the check as a function to shorten you code.

```
class RangeError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, min_, max_):
        self.min_ = min_
        self.max_ = max_

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Input value must be between {self.min_} and {self.max_}.'

def range_check(x, min_, max_):
    if min_ <= x <= max_:
        return x
    raise RangeError(min_, max_)

def get_input_within_range(input_msg, min_, max_):
    mark = range_check(int(input(f"{input_msg} ({min_}-{max_}): ")), min_, max_)
    return mark


assignment_mark = None
project_mark = None
final_exam_mark = None
total_mark = None

while True:
    try:
        if assignment_mark is None:
            assignment_mark = get_input_within_range("Enter assignment mark", 0, 20)
        if project_mark is None:
            project_mark = get_input_within_range("Enter project mark", 0, 30)
        if final_exam_mark is None:
            final_exam_mark = get_input_within_range("Enter final exam mark", 0, 50)
        if total_mark is None:
            total_mark = assignment_mark + project_mark + final_exam_mark
            print(f'Total mark is: {total_mark}')
        else:
            quit_ans = input("Type 'Q' to quit, anything else to restart: ")
            if quit_ans.upper() == 'Q':
                break
            else:
                assignment_mark = None
                project_mark = None
                final_exam_mark = None
                total_mark = None

    except ValueError as e:
        print("Please enter integers")
    except RangeError as e:
        print(e)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```